# How to refresh kartik grid view periodically in yii2

Tags: yii2

I having a yii2 page with ticket information. Example can be seen here
https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-dynagrid/issues/97

I would like to be able to refresh the page periodically or when a records change or when a new has been added.

I have tried something like this but it does not work by some reason

```
$js = '$("#pageReload").on("pjax:end", function() {
       $.pjax.reload({container:".inbox"});  //Reload GridView
   });';
$this->registerJs($js, $this::POS_READY);
$js2 = 'function refresh() {    
$.pjax.reload({container:"#dynagrid-1",timeout: 10000});     
};
refresh();';
$this->registerJs($js2, $this::POS_READY);
$.pjax.reload({container: '#idGridView'});
$.pjax.reload({container: '#pjax-container', timeout: 2000});
$script = <<< JS
$.pjax.reload({container: '#av_list-1-pjax', timeout: 2000});
//JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
```

Comment: It's better to use websockets for such purpose.

Answer (score 2):

this is my solution to refresh the grid every minute

```
setInterval(
function refresh()
{
    $.pjax.reload({
    container:'#task-grid',
    timeout:60000,
})
},10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspect element then get the container of the gridview. It should look something like this `<div id="w0-pjax">` - yours might be different. In this case, `w0-pjax` is the id of the container.

then we can just write the following...

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#w0-pjax'});
```